# How to change MS Visual Studio color of collapsed text and related pop-up menu?

Tags: visual-studio

[MS Visual Studio #region #endregion](https://i.postimg.cc/X7b5VsWK/Screenshot-2024-02-24-213027.png)

How to change color of pop-up menu on the picture and the color of the header of `#region SOME_TEXT #endregion` when it in collapsed state?

I have tried to find it in "Tools", "Options", "Fonts and Colors", but cannot find it.